# How can I get current user's JWT informations?

Tags: python, flask, jwt, flask-jwt-extended

I'm trying the get **all orders that belonging the user that already login to the system**.

I want to get the **id information** of the current user with the **get()** method below and get the order information belonging to **current user** from the order table.
My goal is to get the current user's id from the JWT token using **flask-jwt-extended**.

How can I do that?

```
@api.route('/orders')
@jwt_required()
def get(self):
   # current_user_info
   user_id = current_user_info["id"]
   return UserService.get_orders(user_id)
```

Comment: There are two ways this can be done. 1. Your UI at each call will call get_current_user returning user information and then you develop API /orders/<id> to get the particular user order info. 2. I guess jwt_extended package has get_jwt_identity() using which Id can also be obtained. I prefer 1 personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flask_jwt_extended` provides the `get_jwt_identity()` function, which returns the identity used to create the token used in the current call: `create_access_token(identity=username)`.

[Link to the documentation](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/#flask_jwt_extended.get_jwt_identity)

So in your case, it should become something like this

```
@api.route('/orders')
@jwt_required()
def get(self):
   # current_user_info
   user_id = get_jwt_identity()
   return UserService.get_orders(user_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see the complete documentation for user loading and retrieval here: https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/automatic_user_loading/